# powershell pipe escaping in kubectl exec

Tags: powershell, kubectl

How can I send a simple pipe via kubectl exec on powershell? single commands and parameters work fine.

Works fine in linux and kubectl shell inside rancher:

```
$> kubectl exec test12-7b7fd6b4f4-wzp59 --namespace=test12 -- dmesg | tail -1
[562119.054019] oom_reaper: reaped process 2410 (supervisorctl), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

`kubectl exec` needs the `-- dmesg | tail -1` to be unquoted, but then powershell catches it:

```
PS> kubectl exec test12-7b7fd6b4f4-wzp59 --namespace=test12 -- dmesg | tail -1
tail : The term 'tail' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:168
+ ... namespace=test12 -- dmesg | tail -1
+                                                                  ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (tail:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

if I quote it kubectl complains:

```
PS> kubectl exec test12-7b7fd6b4f4-wzp59 --namespace=test12 -- "dmesg | tail -1"
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "dmesg | tail -1": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
command terminated with exit code 126
```

Commands and parameters work:

```
PS> kubectl exec test12-7b7fd6b4f4-wzp59 --namespace=test12 -- ls -l /var/log/lastlog 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root utmp 2920292 Jan 27 09:56 /var/log/lastlog
```

I found this link and have tried all of them even the stop parse `--%` but none worked: https://www.octopus.com/blog/powershell-pipe-escaping

A naive workaround is to create aliases in the container when building it:
`alias ll='dmesg|tail -1'`

and append it to `~./bashrc`

Comment: What about `-- dmesg '|' tail -1`?

Comment: fails in kubectl: `time="2023-01-31T11:58:07+01:00" level=error msg="invalid input 1 in flag"`

Comment: Wait, `tail -1` isn't actually being passed to `kubectl`, is it? It gets `dmesg`, and the `| tail -1` pipes the output of `kubectl` executing `dmesg` to the host shell, which `tail`s it, unless my understanding of how shell escaping works is completely wrong. This means your original command is right, but fails because `tail` can't be found (because you're running on Windows?) The PowerShell native equivalent would be `| select -last 1`.

Comment: Does powershell supports 'Kubectl' directly to use pipe? You may have to store the log in a file and then use Get-content -Tail.

Comment: @Dilly B: That works but files may be very large and most pods have alpine bash + bash tools already installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pipe works if you wrap it into a sh command:

```
ps> kubectl exec id-pro-trk-trk-user-portal-web-production-747b88964c-rqt75 \
 --namespace=id-pro-trk-trk-user-portal-web-production \
 -- sh -c 'wget -O- http://localhost:8082/user-portal/bp-internal/info | grep version'
```

output:

```
Connecting to localhost:8082 (127.0.0.1:8082)
writing to stdout
-                    100% |********************************|   818  0:00:00 ETA
written to stdout
  "version" : "1.10.247",
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jeroen Mostert comment, we can filter it all back in poweshell. It is not the perfect solution because it will drag all output back to powershell and not just clip it off in the container:

```
ps> kubectl exec test1-6974dc7b79-zf5r5 --namespace=test1 -- dmesg | select -last 1
[578268.156685] oom_reaper: reaped process 20236 (supervisorctl), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

I'm not either able to use the same command in linux and powershell. So Nice if someone has a smarter way :-)

Comment: If you need to do it in the container I'm pretty sure you'll need to invoke the shell explicitly (in Linux as well), because otherwise you have no support for pipe redirection -- so something like `kubectl exec test1.. --namespace.. -- /bin/sh "-c dmesg | tail -1"`, or possibly the `'|'` escape again (shell syntax makes my head hurt).